# « Focus » ou « accent »

Tags: vocabulaire, anglicismes

Quelle expression est correcte ?

> Un court séminaire de mécanique des milieux continus non linéaires
>   avec un **accent** particulier en cinématique non linéaire.

ou

> Un court séminaire de mécanique des milieux continus non linéaires
>   avec un **focus** particulier en cinématique non linéaire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Focus" n'est pas un mot français. Donc la deuxième phrase n'est pas correcte. Ou en tout cas elle utilise un anglicisme qui n'est pas français ; même le président de la République (française) le fait, donc pourquoi pas...

La première phrase est un peu bof. "**Mettre** l'accent sur [...]" signifie, effectivement, "*to focus on [...]*", "*to emphasize [...]*". Donc on dirait plutôt "avec un accent particulier mis sur [...]", ou même juste "avec un accent sur [...]".

Si on veut des alternatives, on peut par exemple dire "[...] avec une attention particulière portée à la cinématique [...]", ou encore "[...] avec un intérêt particulier porté à [...]".

Comment: On peut considérer, avec sévérité, que ***mettre le focus*** n'est pas français mais il faut alors éviter d'utiliser ***est un peu bof*** qui l'est encore moins ;-)

Comment: Il y a p.-ê. une question à poser du genre « quand focus a-t-il été un doublet savant de foyer en physique, le cas échéant ; c'est l'emprunt ou le latinisme », j'ai vu la référence au _doublet savant_ au DHLF. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

« Focus » [n'est pas un mot français](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/focus). *Accent* est bien le mot adapté qui sera compris par n'importe quelle personne dont la langue maternelle est le français.

Par contre, on dit *accent sur* et pas *accent en*, ainsi :

> Un court séminaire de mécanique des milieux continus non linéaires avec un accent particulier **sur la** cinématique non linéaire.

Comment: Pour info, on ne met pas de majuscule à "français" si ce n'est pas utilisé comme un nom qui se réfère à une personne. Donc "Je suis français" (adjectif), "Le français est une langue parlée en France" (le nom de la langue), mais "Les Français parlent français" (adjectif substantivé). C'est pareil pour toutes les langues/nationalités d'ailleurs, "un chapeau mexicain" sans majuscule.